# Why is right-continuity assumed in the definition of stochastic processes?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $X_t$, $t \geq 0$ be a continuous-time stochastic process taking values on an enumerable set $I$ and assume that $X_t(\omega)$ is right-continuous function of $t$ for any $\omega$ in the probability space.

I read in a book that right continuity is important since it allows to use the following type of identities, for $i \in I$,
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_t = i \mbox{ for some } t \in [0, \infty)   ) \\ = 1 - \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{j_1, \ldots, j_n \neq i   } \mathbb{P} \big (  X_{q_1} = j_1, \ldots, X_{q_n} = j_n \big )
$$
where $q_1$, $\ldots$, $q_n$ is an enumeration of the rationals.

Where is right-continuity used in the above expression and why do we need to consider only the rationals?

Comment: You are missing the condition on $q_1\cdots, q_n$

Answer (score 2):

The way right continuity is used here is that if $X_t(\omega) = i$ then there exists some interval $[t, t+\varepsilon]$ such that $X_s(\omega) = i$ for all $s \in [t, t+\varepsilon]$ (this also uses the fact that $X$ takes values in $I$, but it's a similar idea for more general processes).  Since every interval has to contain a rational number, this implies that we can just check rational times because if $X_t(\omega) = i$ for some $t \in [0, \infty)$ then we must also have that $X_t(\omega) = i$ for some *rational* time $t \in [0,\infty)$.  Hence \begin{align*} \{\omega : X_t(\omega) = i \text{ for some } t \in [0,\infty)\} &= \{\omega : X_t(\omega) = i \text{ for some rational } t \in [0,\infty)\} \\
 &= \bigcup_{q_n \in \mathbb{Q}} \{\omega : X_{q_n}(\omega) = i \}.\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, why do you write $q_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ instead of $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, namely why $n$?

Comment: I suppose that's not strictly necessary, $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ would've been fine.  I think that's probably just a force of habit and to really emphasize that it's a countable union.

Comment: If the process is right continuous, would your conclusion hold the same way when checking for $X_t=i$ a.s. on some interval?

Comment: @MathR I think so?  I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but if $X$ is right continuous then $\{\omega : X_t(\omega)=i \text{ for all }t \in (a,b)\} = \bigcap_{q \in \mathbb{Q}\cap (a,b)} \{\omega : X_q(\omega)=i\}$.  Again, let me know if that's what you were looking for, or if you meant something different.